# How can my Discord Bot disconnect from the Voicechannel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a simple Discord Bot(wirtten in Python 3) that just connects and disconnects after a command. The Connect command works fine but my Discconect command doesnt work. Here is the code snippet with both commands:

````
async def join(message):
    channel = message.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()


@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def leave(message):
    channel = message.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.disconnect()```
````

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so you should include the errors in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `leave` function by :

```py
@commands.command()
    async def leave(ctx):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await ctx.send(f'Disconnecting from channel **{channel}**')
            await voice.disconnect()
        else:
            await ctx.send("I'm not connected in any channel")
```